How do I introduce and use plotly in vue3
Recently, it is necessary to use plotly.js in vue3 project, but using npm i, it is always suggested that it has not been introduced.
I would like to ask whether there is a complete introduction process about introducing and using plotly.js

I tried the "import like JS option" but it became dirty and confusing over with time.
Seems like this one could help simplify that (on my way to test it...): https://github.com/VanOord/vue3-plotly
Maybe also consider some other option like chartjs?
